# View creation in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter to developing an application. My doubt is in the view i am using normal html tags. Is it a good method or should I use codeigniter's native tags for creating html tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way is:

you should use the codeigniter **native tags**, because, it achieves the better security mechanaism the ci framework have. (security features such as **xss_clean** are worked with the ci tags)...